# Translation of "by bus/car/train/plane/boat"

Tags: traduction, prépositions

"I'm going to Paris by bus/car/train/plane/boat"

Is it possible to use both "en" and "par" in the translation?

> Je vais aller à Paris en bus/voiture/train/avion/bateau.

or

> Je vais aller à Paris par le bus/la voiture/le train/l'avion/le bateau.

Comment: Note that while *en* is right with the modes of transport you cite, *à* should be used with feet, horse, motorcycle, bicycle, ski,  (*à pied, à cheval, à moto, à vélo, à ski*) but not with skate, surf, rollers (*en planche à roulette/en skate, en surf, en patins à roulette/en rollers,…*) A lot of people wrongly say *en vélo* though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both are acceptable:

- The first is more standard, more frequent and shorter.
- The second would be used to emphasize the transportation mode, typically when making a comparison. Sometimes, the article is omitted ("par train").

According to the respective websites, you travel to Evian *[par train](http://www.evian-tourisme.com/venir-a-evian.html)*, but you travel to Paris *[en train](http://www.parisinfo.com/paris-pratique/se-rendre-a-paris)*. I would say that the second sounds more proper.